# How can I delete Android Studio's emulator

Tags: android-studio

Since I updated the emulator in android studio, my computer has become excessively slow. Is there a way to delete it?

Answer (score 29):

Go to

C:\user\username.android\avd

delete the folder and restart the IDE.

Comment: For mac users its /Users/<username>/.android/avd.  On a mac, make sure that you show your hidden files (command+shift+.) to see the .android file location.  Based on the mac location, I'm guessing there is a slash missing from the windows location in this post.  C:\user\username\.android\avd

Answer (score 17):

In an Android Studia go to **Tools -> AVD Manager**. In a new window have a list with your emulators. You choose emulator which you want to delete, and in righе side a have a button in the form of a triangle (Spinner or DropDownList). In this list have an option "Delete".

Answer (score 16):

You can uninstall from Android Studio by going to **Tools** in the menu and selecting **SDK Manager**, and then the **SDK Tools** tab and unchecking the box for **Android Emulator** and then clicking **Apply**.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you need to find the SDK home directory on your computer and remove the system images folder there.

However, the emulator files themselves only take disk space and disk space often isn't a reason for a slow computer assuming you defrag regularly and clean up other temp files

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if the scheme has changed since Adrians Boh answered, but it's

```
C:\Users\<username>\.android\avd to find your Emulators
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to tools then to avd manager you will find there all emulators you have downloaded...choose option you want..whether to edit or delete

Answer (score 0):

**Remove AVD**

```
Tools -> AVD Manager -> Delete
```

[image]

MacOS location

```
~/.android/avd
//e.g.
/Users/alex/.android/avd
```

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio Giraffe:

Select **Tools** window ---> **Device Manager**

Choose the emulator you want to delete. Tap on More button and **Delete**.

[image]

[image]